# What does this quote mean "Call no chain strong, Which holds one rusted link."

Tags: meaning, poetry, quotations

What does the quote mean from the poem *Protest* by Ella Wheeler Wilcox mean?

"Call no chain strong, Which holds one rusted link."?

Here is the section:

> Therefore I do protest against the boast
>   Of independence in this
>   mighty land.
>   **Call no chain strong, which holds one rusted link.**
>   Call no land free, that holds one fettered slave.
>   Until the manacled
>   slim wrists of babes
>   Are loosed to toss in childish sport and glee,
>   Until the mother bears no burden, save
>   The precious one beneath her
>   heart, until
>   God’s soil is rescued from the clutch of greed
>   And
>   given back to labor, let no man
>   Call this the land of freedom.

Comment: It's unusual (stylised, poetic) reordering and rephrasing of what would more naturally be expressed as *Don't say a chain is strong if it contains even a single rusted link*. Or, as the "idiomatic standard" has it, *A chain is only as strong as its weakest link.* Exactly the same technique applies to the following line, which effectively means *You can't say that a country is "free" if it allows slaves in chains.*

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually asking about this phrase, or about this phrase in context of the poem?

This is a very simple phrase. You just need to think about it.

You have a brand new steel chain everything is very shiny and strong, it is really hard to break.

Now you imagine the same chain with a single rusty link, how hard is it to break the chain now? very simple indeed.

Now if you want an analysis of it in the poem that isn't my strength

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is good, but perhaps it is the poetic and slightly archaic phrasing that is confusing you?  A more simple and direct way of saying it would be:  "If a chain has even one link that is rusty, it can not be called strong".